# Derive equation with integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone know how to find the differentation of this equation. I am really lost and have no idea how to solve this. I found some example and tried do the same but it was making no sence to me. here comes the equation

$$u_2(x)=W(u_1,u_2)(x_0)u_1(x)\int_0^x \frac{e^{-{\int_{x_0}^t} p_1(s)ds}}{u_1^2(t)}dt$$

Hope anyone know how to solve this

Comment: Is this what you intended $$u_2(x)=W(u_1,u_2)(x_0)u_1(x)\int_0^x \frac{e^{{\int_{x_0}^t} p_1(s)ds}}{u_1^2(t)}dt$$
?

Comment: yes i was trying to do this :)

Comment: but there is suppose to be minus sign in front of the integral in the power of e

Comment: there was not a minus in the original one. so try editing my edit with a minus where you want :)

Comment: Can you give more context to this? What is $u_2$ solving? As it is, you question is sort of meaningless without giving some more context.

Comment: $$u_2 $$ is a solution to a second order linear equation. I need to differentiate $$u_2$$ twice to find some solution for other second order linear equation

Comment: Chain rule + fundamental theorem of calculus seems to be the way to go